# environmental variables in batch file

Tags: batch-file

In my batch file, I have set QTLIBS, QTMAKE, QTTOOLS from my C:/ drive where I have the Qt installed. But what if I want the batch file to read from an environmental variable, maybe somewhat like %QTLIBSDIR%

Comment: Unclear, what is your question ? Are you asking if it's the correct way to do for those ?

Comment: I am setting QTLIBS, QTMAKE, QTTOOLS from their absolute path, I want to set from the environmental variables

Answer (score 1):

Actually you gave your own answer;
For example if i have c:\dowork.bat and this is set by an environment variable **DOWORK**;

```
call %DOWORK%
```

And it is done...

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SET QTLIBSDIR=C:\QT5

SET "QTLIBS=%QTLIBSDIR%\lib"
SET "QTMAKE=%QTLIBSDIR%\bin\qtmake"
SET "QTTOOLS=%QTLIBSDIR%\tools"
```

*(I made up all these paths, BTW.)*